# Different performance in creating class with reference

Tags: c#, .net, performance, jit

I found a little strange thing in C# for me.. I have class A, containing only one reference to A. Then I create new object A in every iteration inside for loop, with reference to object created in previous iteration. But If I change reference to object created before for loop, it is much faster. Why it is so?

```
class A
{
    private A next;

    public A(A next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }
}

var a = new A(null);

for (int i = 0; i < 10*1000*1000; i++)
    a = new A(a);

// Takes 1.5s

var b = new A(null);
for (int i = 0; i < 10*1000*1000; i++)
    a = new A(b);

// Takes only 0.17s
```

I found this during implementation of immutable stack in usual way and throught [VList](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/64410/files/techlists.pdf) which was due to that much faster.

Comment: At a guess, it's because in the second case, each time `a = new A(b)` is called, the reference to the old `A` instance is lost, so the CLI can re-use its memory. In the first case, extra memory has to be allocated to hold the 10 million instances you create as you keep references to all of them.

Comment: Small tip but always do some kind of basic sanity/correctness check of the data when doing timing tests like these, especially when you're seeing such astronomically different timing results. You don't want to get too excited about a fast but incorrect solution. As they say, something which gives the wrong result twice as fast is infinitely slower.

Answer (score 2):

This code (your second snippet):

```
var b = new A(null);
for (int i = 0; i < 10*1000*1000; i++)
    a = new A(b);
```

Would be functionally equivalent to this code:

```
 var b = new A(null);
 a = new A(b);
```

Your first snippet isn't the same:

```
var a = new A(null);

for (int i = 0; i < 10*1000*1000; i++)
    a = new A(a);
```

Although it looks like you are throwing away everything but the last reference you, are not. That last instance of `A` has a reference to the previous one, which has a reference to the one before that, which references the one before that...all the way back through 10,000,000 objects. No wonder it's slower.

So comparing two pieces of code that don't actually achieve the same result is kind of pointless. Use the one that actually works (your first snippet) and not the second one. Slower code that works is *definitely* better than faster code that doesn't.

Finally, C# has a perfectly good selection of collection classes (like `List<T>`) that work just fine. Not sure why you want to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: This seems like the obvious answer, but I wonder how OP is measuring the time taken. There's no way `var b = new A(null); a = new A(b);` takes 170ms to execute.

Comment: @JasonWatkins: Thinking about this some more and playing around with it a little, I think it's more likely that it's reusing heap memory as some others have suggested. I don't think it can actually optimize the loop away altogether.

Comment: I don't reinvented wheel, I implement **immutable** collections which preserve all versions (see data structures in functional programming). I suppose it would be some kind of JIT optimization but not that you mentioned. In VList I create all values so JIT cannot skip for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are measuring the cost of using memory.  The slow version allocates 120 megabytes and all objects are referenced through the *next* object references. Short from the cost of allocating the address space, I see 21 gen #0 collections, 17 gen #1 collections and 2 expensive gen #2 collections.  The background GC cannot help because of the high allocation rate.

The buggy fast version gives the garbage collector a very easy time.  The allocated objects are not referenced anywhere so the fast gen #0 collection collects all of them.  It uses very little memory, just the gen #0 segment and there are no gen #1 and gen #2 collections.

You've otherwise probably discovered a basic truth about immutable objects.  The type guarantees are nice but the concept does not translate well to the way the machine works.  Processors are heavily optimized to make mutable objects very efficient, immutable ones are cache unfriendly, memory hungry and give the GC a lot of work.  Simplest example is String vs StringBuilder, most programmers know when to switch to the mutable version.  Also one of the basic reasons, I think, why Roslyn was so late, meeting the perf goal set by the old C# compiler must have been an enormous battle.

Answer (score 1):

When you run an application under **.NET Framework**, the memory is allocated on the `Heap` under the hood using the **Managed Code** features available on high level programming languages like **C#/VB.Net** and **Java**.

When you create an instance of a class by using the keyword `new`, the programming language tells the compiler that it wants to allocate memory on the `heap` (**dynamic allocation**). This allocation demands time because it has to pass **OS** requests restrictions and processes. When you request memory allocation via a High Level programming language, it will allocate a bigger block (a **buffer**) under the hood. Thus, future "instantiations" demand less time due to the fact that there is already available memory for the application on the `heap`.

Answer (score 1):

David and Matt are correct. If you take care to profile the application you will find for the first sample

```
GC Generation GC Count
     0        3 
     1        17 
     2        2
```

and your second sample

```
GC Generation  GC Count
   0           28 
   1           0 
   2           0
```

With your first code you create a large linked list which still contains all objects which are never released until the application terminates.

```
• Max GC Heap Size: 119,546 MB
```

whereas for your second sample you get

```
• Max GC Heap Size: 4,217 MB
```

Doing a

```
var a = new Container();
loop
{
 a = new Container(a) 
}
```

will keep the data because a will contain a reference to the "old" a.
Whereas

```
b = new Container();
loop
{
   a = new Container(b) 
}
```

will assign onle one container which contains one further instance but not the complete history of previously allocated objects. 
The moral of the story is to closely look at where you root your objects. If you create a large linked list of nodes it is what you get.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like CLR optimization, because in second case variable a is unused.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you are creating a chain of 10,000,000 connected objects, where as in the second case you are creating 10,000,000 separate objects connected to a single instance of A. My guess is that the slow down is due to the framework having to perform heap management when allocating 10,000,000 connected objects, vs randomly allocating individual objects.